# Rails 3 updating multiple of the same element on a page using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that has some simple functionality, allowing the user to save/unsave posts.

It does this nice and ajaxy, like so:

view:

```
<p id="save_<%= frugle.id %>">
  <%= link_to "Save", new_saveds_path(current_user.id, :post_id => post.id), :remote => true %>
</p>
```

controller:

```
class SavedsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @follow = Saved.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :post_id => params[:post_id])
    @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html "save_#{@post.id}", "#{link_to "Unsave", saveds_path(current_user.id, :post_id => @post.id), :method => :delete, :remote => true }"
    end
  end
```

This works fine and dandy.  My question comes in, as sometimes, on the homepage, the user has a whole lot of posts being viewed, and occasionally the same post shows up twice. If the user goes to save this post, the RJS above will just change the first p with that particular id that it comes across then stop.  Is there any way to update all the p with that id on a single page?

That makes sense right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "update all the 'p's with that id", because by definition only one element on the page has a given id.

However, if you give all your `<p>`s a *class* according to their *rails id*, you can do what you want.

Example:

```
<p class="object-1234">test</p>
<p class="object-5678">another test</p>
<p class="object-1234">test</p>
```

Now you can do:

```
$('.object-1234').hide()
```

And get the desired effect.

**edit**:
Also, this assumes you're using jQuery in your AJAX views. I strongly advise you to do so - it's more useful than the built-in rjs.
Here's a screencast about it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Comment: i agree, i would like to go to jquery, but the site is mostly built using the default rjs. Is it possible to use the RJS to update elements by class instead of id?

Comment: page.select('.someclass').each do |element|
  page.replace_html element, "<p>OHAI</p>"
end